# Error loading properties of Java xlsx files. [ERROR] Malformed \uxxxx encoding

Tags: java, properties, xlsx

Can anyone help?

```
        input = new FileInputStream(this.tmpFullFileName);
        // load a properties file
        prop.load(input);
```

When I try to load a xlsx file property.

```
[ERROR] Malformed \uxxxx encoding.
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.invokeServiceClass(RPCUtil.java:212)
at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(RPCMessageReceiver.java:121)
at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:40)
at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:114)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using "\" for file destinations, try to edit to "/".

Comment: I tried with filePath: /tmp/ad53fb4c-831c-4437-887a-5a9afc221dac or /tmp/file.xlsb

Comment: While loading the file, it seems like there is a problem. Did you analyze the file ? Dit it contain any backslash ?

Comment: I'm really sorry that I've wasted your time.
I needed to extract the custom properties Excel document.  
I used:
 xlsx - Apache poi
 xlsm and xlsb - just unzipped and found properties in docProps/custom.xml

Comment: Don't worry, the essential is that you found out !